# Fast selection of a block of following records

Tags: mysql, sql, specifications

Is there an implementation of SQL database allowing to select from a table the block of n following records -- in respect of the index -- starting from a specified index, with performance `O(n + log tables_size)`? But also allowing adding a record in `O(log tables_size)`. If so, how to do it?

I'm probably a dreamer but, is it possible with MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` is the primary key on a table, then the following will return in order of the time needed to fetch the records, plus the initial index seek:

```
select t.*
from t
where id >= SOMEID
order by id
limit <n>;
```

Adding a record consists of two parts.  The first part is finding available space and the second part is inserting into the index.  A b-tree index should require `O(log table_size)` for an insert.  If the pages are full and you are only inserting at the end of the table, then finding the right page is constant time.

In other words, if I understand your question correctly, primary key clustered indexes do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes, it is something I have been thinking about. But I was afraid, that the selection mechanism may be not smart enough and perform iteration through whole tree, up to finding n matching records. While it is enough to find the initial index, which takes `O(log tables_size)`, and then fetch the rest of the records in `O(n + log tables_size)`. Is the mechanism really smart enough?

Comment: @Number47 . . . Yes.  The selection mechanism known as an "index scan" recognizes that the `where` clause and `order by` clause imply reading through the records in the index sequentially, from the starting point on the `where` clause.

Comment: OK. So it understands, the first element of the result is the record of SOMEID id and then do in-order traversal to find the rest? Sorry, for asking three times about the same, but it is easy for misunderstandings here. Ow, what implementation are you talking about?

Comment: @Number47 . . . This is called an "index scan" and every major database does it.